# Creating a static average price method

Tags: java

Good afternoon, I can't write a static method to calculate the average price

Implement a static method to calculate the average price of goods in all baskets. It should calculate and return the ratio of the total cost of all baskets to the total number of all items.
Implement the static method for calculating the average cost of a basket (the ratio of the total cost of all baskets to the number of baskets).

I still have not been able to create static method data

```
public class Basket {

    private static int count = 0;
    private String items = "";
    private int totalPrice = 0;
    private double totalWeight = 0;
    private int limit;

    public static int allprice = 0;
    public static int allcount = 0;
    public static int averagebasket = 0;

    public Basket() {
        increaseCount(1);
        items = "Список товаров:";
        this.limit = 1000000;
    }

    public Basket(int limit) {
        this();
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public Basket(String items, int totalPrice) {
        this();
        this.items = this.items + items;
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public static int getAllTovar() {
        return allcount;
    }

    public static int getAllPrice() {
        return allprice;
    }
    public static int getAverageBasket() {
        return averagebasket;
    }

    public double getTotalWeight(){
        return totalWeight;
    }

    public static void increaseCount(int count) {
        Basket.count = Basket.count + count;
    }

    public static void increaseTovar(int count) {
        Basket.allcount = Basket.allcount + count;
    }

    public static void increasePrice(int totalPrice) {
        Basket.allprice = Basket.allprice + totalPrice;
    }

    public static void average() {
        Basket.averagebasket = allprice / allcount;
    }

    public void add(String name, int price, double weight) {
        add(name, price, 1, weight);
    }

    public void add(String name, int price, int count, double weight) {
        boolean error = false;
        if (contains(name)) {
            error = true;
        }

        if (totalPrice + count * price >= limit) {
            error = true;
        }

        if (error) {
            System.out.println("Error occured :(");
            return;
        }
        increaseTovar(1);
        items = items + "\n" + name + " - " +
                count + " шт. - " + price + " Вес - " + totalWeight;
        totalPrice = totalPrice + count * price;
        totalWeight = totalWeight +  weight;
        Basket.allprice += price * count;
    }

    public void clear() {
        items = "";
        totalPrice = 0;
    }

    public int getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public boolean contains(String name) {
        return items.contains(name);
    }

    public void print(String title) {
        System.out.println(title);
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Корзина пуста");
        } else {
            System.out.println(items);
        }
    }
}
`

`public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Basket basket = new Basket();
        basket.add("Milk", 40, 305.4);
        basket.print("Milk");
        //System.out.println(Basket.getCount());
        Basket vasya = new Basket();
        basket.add("bread", 60, 555);
        System.out.println(Basket.getAllTovar());
        System.out.println((Basket.getAllPrice()));
        System.out.println(Basket.getAverageBasket());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 public static double getAveragePrice() {
        return (double) allPrice / allCount;
    }
    
    public static double getAverageBasket() {
        return (double) allPrice / basketCount;
    }
```

Comment: Posting speculative answers is discouraged. We should rather ask for clarification in the comments. --- Posting code-only answer is discouraged. We should rather explain the challenge(s), and how our solution tackles it (them).